# Can't see shared files in Docker container

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, pytorch, opencv

I'm trying to build a docker image that contains pytorch and cv2.

```
docker build -t test .\Desktop\Docker\Docker_image
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM pytorch/pytorch:latest

RUN conda install -c conda-forge opencv

WORKDIR ./work

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "./my_script.py" ]
```

**my_script.py:**

```py
import cv2
import os
import sys
import shutil

print('we start')
print(os.listdir(os.getcwd()))
print('what is in?')
print(os.listdir(os.getcwd() + '/Volume/'))
```

**Then I run the container:**

```
docker run --name test-container -v C:\Users\user\Desktop\Docker\Volume\.:/work/Volume/ test
```

And I can't see any files when use os.listdir(*path*) in the volume directory, but I can copy files using the cp command...

```
docker cp test-container:/work/Results/. C:\Users\user\Desktop\Results
```

So what should I do to see files in the volume directory (my main code uses these files) and be able to use pytorch and cv2?

Comment: Are you using docker-compose.yml?

Comment: @Ashok no, i am not

Comment: Try this to build docker build -t test ../Desktop/Docker/Docker_image

Comment: What is the value of `os.getcwd()`?  (The relative path `WORKDIR ./test` could pick up an alternate working directory from the base image; you could directly specify an absolute path `WORKDIR /test` too.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Tried it. doesn't work.